# Templates and Syntax

Tags: c++, templates

Working on an algorithm to look at a STL container of STL strings (or other strings, making it general)

Basically it loops through something like a std::list and returns the length of the longest beginning in common. It's for processing lists of files, like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Stuff.exe
C:\Windows\Things\InHere.txt
C:\Windows\Foo\Bar.txt
```

This should return 11, because "`C:\Windows\`" is in common.

Never written a templatized function before, and my compiler is complaining. Here's my code:
Header:

```
// longestBegin.h -- Longest beginning subsequence solver
template <typename SequenceSequenceT, typename SequenceT, typename T >
size_t longestBegin(InputIterator firstCandidates, InputIterator lastCandidates);
```

---

Implementation:

```
// longestBegin.cpp -- Longest beginning subsequence solver
#include <stdafx.h>

template <typename SequenceSequenceT, typename SequenceT, typename T >
size_t longestBegin(InputIterator firstCandidates, InputIterator lastCandidates)
{
    SequenceT firstString = *firstCandidates;
    size_t longestValue = firstString.length();
    firstCandidates++;
    for(size_t idx = 0; idx < longestValue; idx++)
    {
        T curChar = firstString[idx];
        for(InputIterator curCandidate = firstCandidates;curCandidate != lastCandidates; curCandidate++)
        {
            if ((*curCandidate)[idx] != curChar)
                return idx - 1;
        }
    }
    return longestValue;
}
```

I have a funny feeling I'm missing something fundamental here......

The compiler bombs with the following error:

```
error C2998: 'size_t longestBegin' : cannot be a template definition
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Billy3

Comment: please increase the readability of your code here by removing the copyright messages

Comment: And indicate in your code where you are getting the error message

Comment: Okay, but simply copying the comment of the one above you doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your parameter names in the `template` line need to include any types of function parameters or return types. This means that you need to mention `InputIterator` in your template parameter list. Try changing your function declaration to:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
size_t longestBegin(InputIterator firstCandidates, InputIterator lastCandidates)
```

Your next problem is: how does the compiler know what `SequenceT` is? The answer is that it's the result of dereferencing an `InputIterator`. Iterators that aren't pointers have a nested `typedef` called `reference`, which is just what you need here. Add this to the start of your function so the compiler knows what `SequenceT` is:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
size_t longestBegin(InputIterator firstCandidates, InputIterator lastCandidates)
{
    typedef typename InputIterator::reference SequenceT;
[etc.]
```

You could have kept `SequenceT` as a template parameter, but then the compiler couldn't guess what it is from looking at the arguments, and you'd have to call your function by typing e.g. `longestBegin<string>(arguments)`, which isn't necessary here.

Also, you'll notice that this doesn't work if `InputIterator` is a pointer -- pointers don't have nested typedefs. So you can use a special struct called `std::iterator_traits` from the `<iterator>` standard header that can sort out these problems for you:

```
//(At the top of your file)
#include <iterator>

template <typename InputIterator>
size_t longestBegin(InputIterator firstCandidates, InputIterator lastCandidates)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::reference SequenceT;
[etc.]
```

Finally, unless the first string is always the longest, you could end up accessing a string past the end of its array inside the second for loop. You can check the length of the string before you access it:

```
//(At the top of your file)
#include <iterator>

template <typename InputIterator>
size_t longestBegin(InputIterator firstCandidates, InputIterator lastCandidates)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::reference SequenceT;
    SequenceT firstString = *firstCandidates;
    size_t longestValue = firstString.length();
    firstCandidates++;
    for(size_t idx = 0; idx < longestValue; idx++)
    {
        T curChar = firstString[idx];
        for(InputIterator curCandidate = firstCandidates;curCandidate != lastCandidates; curCandidate++)
        {
                if (curCandidate->size() >= idx || (*curCandidate)[idx] != curChar)
                        return idx - 1;
        }
    }
    return longestValue;
}
```

Also note that the function returns `(size_t)(-1)` if there is no common prefix.

Comment: Yeah.. there are problems with the logic of that code... it was slap together to see how the syntax worked. Thank you though :)

Comment: @Doug: I believe your answer miss some lines, the template declaration  list is unomplete. I guess you are interested to know that , don"t you? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't forward declare templates, I believe. Try moving the implementation into the header file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'll first need to put the implementation into the header file since it's a template function and only "implemented" at compile time.

Comment: Not ripping on your answer. However "kitchen" was faster ;)

Answer (score 1):

InputIterator is not a type I think.
Can you declare

```
InputIterator x;
```

in your code or you get an error?

Comment: That is true, but not the cause of the failure I'm questioning.